# Raspberry Pi Python Tkinter update label image

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I am trying to update an image in the following code and I am trying to call self.changeRarrow() in order to do that. The one problem is that I have no idea how to edit this code to update once it is called? Currently I am trying to change a global variable and then destroy the label and recreate it using the new parameters, but I saw something about using a LabelR.config(image=y) in order to update the label. I tried that but it wouldn't let me reference the LabelR from any other function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! I am open to major code changes also.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.bind("<KeyRelease-a>", self.on_a_release)
    self.bind("<KeyRelease-d>", self.on_d_release)
    self.bind("<KeyRelease-w>", self.on_w_release)
    self.bind("<KeyRelease-s>", self.on_s_release)
    self.bind("<Key>", self.key)
    self.title("RC Command Center")
    self.geometry("500x500")
    self.initUI()
    self.arrowLeft()
    self.arrowRight()

def arrowLeft(self):
    leftArrow = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("arrowLeft.png"))
    labelL = Label(image=leftArrow)
    labelL.image = leftArrow
    labelL.pack(side="left")

def arrowRight(self):
    x = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(y))
    #photos = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("arrowRight.png")), ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("arrowRightR.png"))]
    labelR = Label(image=x)
    labelR.image = x
    labelR.pack(side="right")


def changeRarrow(self):
     global y
     y = "arrowRightR.png"
     labelR.destroy()
     self.arrowRight()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be the garbage collector. 
Two known workarounds are suitable for your situation.
 Either use a class for your app   and declare the image as a class variable (self) or make it global.

"X" is referenced, not deep copied and as a result of beeing a local variable it is garbage collected.
Garbage collected reference means no reference at all for the used locations.